# Determining Darkest and Lightest Color

Tags: vb.net

I have an image loaded into a picture box, and need some help with a way to detect the Darkest color present in the image, the Lightest color present, and the color which is in the middle.
The point being so that I can refine my heightmap generator based on these 3 colors.

I'm thinking of looping through each X,Y coordinate within the picture box, set the darkest and lightest value, and overwrite those values if a darker/lighter one is found. 
The part I'm stuck at is determining what exactly I can use to check how dark or light a spot within the picture box is. RGB?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to convert each colour from RGB to [HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and look at the Lightness value.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getbrightness(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey or just do that! I didn't know that was in the framework.

Comment: Woah I feel silly. Thank you Hans!

Comment: Now, how to I get the middle color? Like the color with the brightness in between the darkest and lightest?

Comment: Do you need an actual color that's in the image? If not, just construct one with brightness of `min+((max+min)/2)`. If you do, then you should iterate over the image again and find the one with the brightness that's closest to that value.